# Common practice for function calls debug logging

Tags: python, logging, pep

In the same way as PEP8, etc. are there some reference standard practice (like [Google Python Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html)) that are widely used in the industry about function/methods logging?

```
class MyObject:
   def my_method(self)
       logger.debug("my_method: starting...")   # or "beginning" 
       ...
       logger.debug("my_method: finished.")     # or "end" etc. 
       return ...
```